# how to update datetime cell in MySql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update an event date & time saved in one cell, I got everything right except the date is not updated,. My update works except the event date & time.

```
$id            = $_POST['id']; 
$package       = $_POST['package']; 
$type          = $_POST['type']; 
$shortdesc     = $_POST['shortdesc']; 
$vanue         = $_POST['vanue'];
$event_start   = $_POST['fmt_date'] . ' ' . $_POST['fmt_time'] . 'Y-m-d H:i:s';


$sql="UPDATE event_table SET package='$package', type='$type', 
shortdesc='$shortdesc', vanue='$vanue', 
event_start= '$event_start'  WHERE id ='$id' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: do you get result with $_POST['fmt_date'] and $_POST['fmt_time']? And do you really enter 'Y-m-d H:i:s' string to database?

Answer (score 1):

```
// You should properly format the date for validity in insertion
$id            = $_POST['id']; 
$package       = $_POST['package']; 
$type          = $_POST['type']; 
$shortdesc     = $_POST['shortdesc']; 
$vanue         = $_POST['vanue'];

// if date formatted well used this...
$event_start   = $_POST['fmt_date'] . ' ' . $_POST['fmt_time'];

//if not format date
$event_start = date_format($event_start, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

// or if it comes to be a string..
$event_start = strtotime($event_start);

$sql="UPDATE event_table SET package='$package', type='$type', 
shortdesc='$shortdesc', vanue='$vanue', 
event_start=now()  WHERE id ='$id' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: i think OP posting date so we can not use now()..because date may vary

Comment: Kaii   I have an input form where I enter the date and time I want, I don't the current date and time but I rather want to choose the date and time my self

Comment: @SimanMaxamed so what is wrong with your code..?? what error it gave.?

Comment: the updated date and time is not inserted in the date and time field.  0000-00-00 00:00:00  is inserted in the date&time cell Dipesh Parmar

Comment: its because of the formatting of the date you inserted.. ,,can we know what format did the $_POST['fmt_date'] and $_POST['fmt_time'] output so we can think of a specific function to format it to a date for validity in insertion.

Comment: have you tried to remove 'Y-m-d H:i:s' and put only $_POST['fmt_date'] . ' ' . $_POST['fmt_time']? That is of course if fmr_date is in format Y-m-d and fmt_time in H:i:s. If not you need to convert it with strtotime and date functions.

Comment: adding 'Y-m-d H:i:s' at the bottom would be necessary to format your date... instead it just concatenated.. So if your date is formatted right adding that will raise an error..

Comment: This is how it is save in MySql database:  2013-03-23 08:26:28

Comment: try to remove the formatting at the buttom insted use only $event_start   = $_POST['fmt_date'] . ' ' . $_POST['fmt_time']

Answer (score 0):

MySQL support the datetime format as follows

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

So you need to format your datetime variable in PHP accordingly which mysql accept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that you will find what you search for on this website: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html